# mod_rewrite for URL with two URL-parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to be able to open the following url

```
http://example.com/login/12345
```

and in the background, it should load:

```
http://example.com/index.php?endpoint=login&access_key=12345
```

Obviously, I have tried many htaccess generators to create an appropriate RewriteRule set.

For example the following (from: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?endpoint=$1&access_key=$2 [L]
```

Even though I know for a fact that .htaccess and mod_rewrite is enabled on my server (i tried to setup a test to redirect all requests from example.com to example2.com using htaccess and mod_rewrite, and it worked), I can't get this to work.

I have now spent nearly 2 hours to find for a solution on stackoverflow and other websites, but all my attempts failed.

I hope someone can help me find out the correct way to rewrite my url in the above example.like explained above.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"?! What does it do or what doesn't it do?

Comment: Is `login` variable? Meaning, could it also be `http://example.com/housenumber/12345` ?

Comment: What is location of your .htaccess file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)/([^\/]*)$ /index.php?endpoint=$1&access_key=$2 [L]
#-Added-these---^--------^
```

When tested, here is the result:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, works like a charm. also, for anyone else wondering what test-tool clami219 used, you can find it here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ Very useful!

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the `.htaccess` file in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT`

**Assuming `login` is not variable**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^login/(\d+)$ index.php?endpoint=login&access_key=$1 [L,NC,DPI]
```

**** If `login` is variable****

This is in case you want to redirect not only for `login`, but also for urls such as `http://example.com/housenumber/12345`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)$ index.php?endpoint=$1&access_key=$2 [L,NC,DPI]
```

Tested on actual Apache 2.2 and 2.4 :)